# android - usb to rs232 with archos 80 G9

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, archos

I am trying to use a usb to RS232 cable (with FTDI chip) with the archos 80 G9.
I have downloaded the FTDI example and istalled it on the archos but it does not recognize the FTDI chip.

there are 2 problem actually:

1) I want to use the 3G USB port of the archos to connect it to the usb to RS232 cable, right now i can not connect anything to the 3G usb port, not keyboard noy disk on key, what should i do in order to use the 3G USB port with regular devices and not the 3G stick?

2) Even if i connect the usb to RS232 cable to the micro usb (with cabe adapter) the archos doe snot recognize the the device. i should say that i can connect keyborad and disk on key that way. how can i make it recognize the usb to RS232 cable?

I prefeer using the 3G USB port of the archos but right now any solution will do,
Thnaks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular size usb port on the back, but you have to use a usb hub with external power supply. I managed connecting several usb2serial ports without problems.